# Subsite specific Page-Layouts......is it possible?

Tags: page-layout

I have created 10 different 'Page Layouts' in SharePoint 2013 UI and customised them using SharePoint Designer 2013. I have a site collection having 2 subsites in it. I want that exactly 6 of those Page Layouts should be available to be used in one of the subsites, and the rest 4 should be available in the other. Is that possible (especially with UI) ?? If yes, please tell in details as I am a fresher just started to work with SharePoint.

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to one of your subsite's Site Settings and then, under Look and Feel, select Page Layouts and Site Templates.

On this screen you can specify that your site only allows a handful of layouts.  Simply click the "Pages in this site can only use the following layouts" radio button and then add the layouts you want to be available on that specific subsite.

You'll need to do this for both of your subsites, adding 6 to one and 4 to the other.